# I want to center my container inside the panel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

This code is placing the container at the top of the panel. This looks bad when run on ipad. I want it to come on centre of the device. can anyone help me please?

This is my code.

Ext.define('Mistfly.view.SignupPanel', {

```
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'signupPanel',

config: {
    id: 'registerationform',
    items: [

        {
            xtype: 'container',
            title: 'Registration Form',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                pack: 'center'
            },
            items:[

            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Registration Form',

                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        label: 'Username',
                        labelWrap: true,
                        name:'username',
                        id: 'usrName',
                        placeHolder: 'Enter Username'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        label: 'Password',
                        labelWrap: true,
                        name: 'password',
                        id:'pwd',
                        placeHolder: 'Enter Password'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'emailfield',
                        label: 'Email',
                        labelWrap: true,
                        name: 'email',
                        id:'mail',
                        placeHolder: 'email@example.com'
                    }
                    ]
            }
                ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                pack: 'center'
            },
            items:[
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    itemId: 'save',
                    width: '20%',
                    text: 'Save',
                    action: 'submitFormAction'
                }
                ]
        }
        ]

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can center your container inside the panel via CSS. For example, you can try this:

```
.panel {
   float:left;
   width:100%;
}

.panel .container {
   width:90%;
   display:table;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/51t

Couple of things to note

1. If you want your container (with the fieldset) to be in the center of the screen, you will need to set layout of it's parent to 'fit' (in your case it is your SignupPanel).  This way you are indicating the child items to occupy 100% of parent.  Please note this layout might is usually not applied if you have multiple child components.
2. You will also have to move the button inside the container.

PS:  You could do as Renier suggested using CSS however i would highly recommend using out-of-the box layout configuration to set your layouts (or at least get close to what you want) and then if needed override it with CSS